# React Native (Expo) + Django app: TypeError: Network request failed

Tags: django, react-native, expo-go

I have a React Native (Expo go) frontend and Django based backend.
I have the django backend setup with some API endpoints, which I am trying to reach from frontend.
When using `npx expo start --tunnel` command instead of `npx expo start` command to launch the frontend, the web requests to the backend fail.

This is the full setup:

In django settings, I have these settings setup:

```
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    'exp://julyt-u-anonymous-8081.exp.direct',
    'http://localhost:19006',
    'http://192.168.153.13:8081',
    '10.0..rest_of_the_ip',
]
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = ('*')
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
```

I am launching the django server with:
`python manage.py runserver 10.0..rest_of_the_ip:8000` 
I am launching the frontend with:
`npx expo start --tunnel`

When sending webrequest to the api endpoint, I get this in the frontend side:
E.g.,  `ERROR  API::loginUser->FAILED TO LOGIN USER:  [TypeError: Network request failed]`

Backend side does not receive anything.

This same setup works when I am using same wifi for both backend and frontend, for example when I am at a cafe:

```
python manage.py runserver local_IPv4:8000
npx expo start
```

And for the record, using npx expo start does not work when I am using this current wifi. The phone (expo go app) won't connect to the server, and thus it is not an option and I have to use the `--tunnel` flag.

I blurred the ip I am using normally, even though the IP starting with 10.0... is probably a local IPv4 address and nothing to worry about.

I tried to change the CORS settings from backend to allow the IP I am using, with no results.